# View isn't rerendering, but my Redux Store updates properly

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm having instances of this happening all throughout my application, but I just implemented redux within my React app, and the state of my application is properly being managed, but my React App isn't rerendering to reflect the changes.

**Here's an example of one of my React Components:**

```js
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import store from "../store/store"
import {updateView} from "../store/actions/index"

function Device(props) {
        props.updateView(props.type, props.objects);
        var state = store.getState().objectView
        store.subscribe(()=>{
            state = store.getState().objectView;
        })
        console.log(state);
        var objcomponent = [];
        state.objects.forEach((obj)=>{
            objcomponent.push(<ObjectComponent info={obj.info} actions={obj.actions}/>)
        });

        return(
            <div className="device-container">
                <div contentEditable className="device-name">Device: {state.type}</div>
                {objcomponent}
           </div>
            )
    }



const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return bindActionCreators({
        updateView: updateView
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Device)
```

In this instance, the Component is supposed to re render showing the new devices. But instead, it would only show new devices if the array size is bigger than in the last render. And it's a partial re-render at that. It would show something like this

```js
//Previous Component
var component = [1, 2]

//Expected new Component
var component = [3, 4, 5]

//Actual new Component
var component = [1, 2, 5]
```

Meanwhile on the Redux store, I could see all the changes that were supposed to happen.

If you think it would help, here are my reducers and actions too. I don't think I am mutating the original state in anyway, but if you have more expertise in Redux, please point that out. I am nothing but a mere novice.

**Action:**

```js
import {UPDATE_VIEW} from "./objectviewactions"

export const updateView = (type,objects)=>{
    return {
        type: UPDATE_VIEW,
        payload: {type: type, objects: [...objects]}
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```js
import {UPDATE_VIEW} from "../actions/objectviewactions";
var initialState = {
    type: "",
    objects: []
}
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case UPDATE_VIEW:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            }
        default: 
            return state
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `ObjectComponent` instances need [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).  When a parent component, e.g. your `device-container` `div` has an array of an arbitrary number of child components, keys allow React to keep straight what can be reused and what needs replacing on on render.

So, you'd invoke `ObjectComponent` like this:

```
<ObjectComponent key={obj.someUniqueIdentifier} info={obj.info} actions={obj.actions}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please **DO NOT** access the Redux store directly inside of a React component like that!  That's what `connect()` is supposed to handle for you.

You should be supplying a `mapStateToProps` function as the first argument to extract whatever data your component needs, and that data will be passed into your component as props.